# Can I Harmonize and join Product data from store-data.zip using marklogic QuickStart?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I'm trying to harmonize (or merge) the Product content in the store-data.zip file available in https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/data/store-data.zip using MarkLogic DHF QuickStart GUI.

> MarkLogic version: 10.0.4 
>   QuickStart version: 5.2.1

I am trying to merge the data in `Products/games/board_games.csv` with the data in `Products/misc/apparel.csv, Products/misc/accessories.csv, Products/misc/extensions.csv` into a single Product Entity.

I am deadly confused but, let me explain the steps I have performed

1. Ingested data in 2 steps (1 for games and the other for misc) using 'Ingestion' step.
2. Created Product Entity with fields from board_games.csv and nested entities from the csvs in the misc
   [Image of Entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGOU3.png)
3. Added mapping steps for each of Apparel,Accessory and Extensions entities and targeted to Product Entity with additional collection `ADDONS`. [Image of Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFjqS.png)
4. Added mapping step for Product(games) and targeted to Product Entity (with no additional collection)
5. Matching step is performed using `Source collection: ADDONS`  and `Target Entity: ProductEntity` with `Match Options: GameId`.
6. Merge step is performed on the `Source Collection: datahubMatchingSummary` and `Target Entity: ProductEntity`

Results are **not** as expected.

**Issues & Questions:**

1. Mapping of the data is not done correctly. Extensions data is
   inserted into Apparel URLs (even after I selected the correct URL
   during the mapping.). Why is it this way? It seems that the last mapping step overrides the others if performed on same target entity. [After mapping result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvhTP.png)
2. After the Matching step,the match-sumamry result collection showed 7 entries containing
   similar matches. Why is it? [After match step result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e00XN.png)
3. Merging results were strange. There was a merge of records based on GameId,
   but was not complete.

Please help. I want to merge these documents. I can't imagine how difficult gradle tasks would be.